# General questions about "for" loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm beginning to learn Python by following an introductory text and have come across an exercise that implements a `for` loop to read files from a directory. I've used `for` loops before in R and Java and I have some questions. I'm hoping the community could help me wrap my head around about `for` loops in general.

1. It seems (in Python at least) that special characters and numbers can't be used as the "name" in loop. What's the reason for this?

   ex:

   ```py
   for @ in data:
       print (@, end= ' ')
   ```

   will produce an error. However replacing `@` with `x` or `name` for example is fine. Is this one of those things we accept, don't question, and move on?
2. How does the `for` loop know (or evaluate) whether an object is "iterable"?

Comment: 1/ Because such are the rules for Python variable names. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: As stated in the doc, '... the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.'

Comment: 2/ It doesn't. If the Python runtime finds out an object is not iterable, you'll get an error, something along the lines of `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: "Is this one of those things we accept, don't question, and move on": you can certainly question it, but there is the necessary logic and though behind it. Mostly not to confuse programmers, and to not clash with other tokens (e.g., a `#` as a variable name would make it impossible to have comment lines. `@` at the start of a line also has a special meaning).

Comment: For a (much) more detailed explanation, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you I will look at the link provided

Comment: If you could use `5` as a variable name, how would you write the number five?

Comment: @jasonharper good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As others have mentioned, see the rules for Python variable, i.e. identifier, names: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers
2. An object is iterable if it has the __next__() method **defined**.  See also https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Note: object is iterable if it has `__iter__` defined. It is just very often that `__iter__` returns `self` so then `__next__` is used afterward.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Reading https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__ , I'd say `__iter__` returns an iterator. But the iterator itself requires `__next__`. To me, this sounds like food for confusion whether an object is iterable (adjective), or an iterable (noun) itself.

Comment: @00 Fair point. But considering the second question from the post: `for` will iterate through object only if it has `__iter__` defined. To be precise: `for` will call `__iter__` on the object and iterate through whatever `__iter__` returns.